# How to make regular expression for text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user model and I have brief introduction "intro" of the user in my user model which is of type string as follows.

```
  VALID_INTRO_REGEX = /\A[a-zA-Z\.\,]+(?: [a-zA-Z\.\,]+)*\z/
  validates :intro, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_INTRO_REGEX, :message => "must contain only letters" }
```

How do I make a regular expression which satisfies the following valid and invalid statements?

```
Valid = "Hey everyone! My name is xxxx. I am from XXX. I do this, I do that."   
Invalid = "<img src= "    
Invalid = "">< img src=x onerror=alert(0);>"
```

Comment: Why not just strip out HTML? There are gems for that.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks. Could you please share some links?

Comment: Stretch your Google-fu, padawan. (Plus requests for resources and tools are OT for SO :)